# Php fwrite/fclose warning

Tags: php, fwrite, fclose

I have the following code fragment which works btw:

```
  $txt = "<?php include 'work/uploads/".$php_id.".html';?>";
  $slot = file_put_contents('../offer/slots.php', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
  fwrite($slot, $txt);
  fclose($slot);
  $theCounterFile = "../offer/count.txt";
  $oc = file_put_contents($theCounterFile, file_get_contents($theCounterFile)+1);
  fwrite($oc);
  fclose($oc);
```

But the following warnings get logged when running it:

```
Line 81 : fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given
Line 82 : fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given
Line 85 : fwrite() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
Line 86 : fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given
```

Probably my logic is wrong here. Maybe someone can shed some light here?

Comment: what are lines 81,82,85 and 86?

Comment: it's b/c you're using those functions incorrectly. look this up in the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `fwrite()` or `fclose()` at all when you use `file_put_contents()`. From [the docs for `file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

> This function is identical to calling `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` successively to write data to a file.

Your code should look like:

```
$file = fopen("../offer/work/uploads/".$php_id.".html","w");
fwrite($file,$data); // Note: you could use file_put_contents here, too...
fclose($file);
$txt = "<?php include 'work/uploads/".$php_id.".html';?>";
$slot = file_put_contents('../offer/slots.php', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
$theCounterFile = "../offer/count.txt";
$oc = file_put_contents($theCounterFile, file_get_contents($theCounterFile)+1);
```

As for why you get errors with your current code: `fwrite()` and `fclose()` expect the first parameter to be a resource (the type of return value you get from `fopen()`). But you're passing them the value returned by `file_put_contents()`, which is an integer. So, you get an error.

Comment: after first line should be like `if (!$file) die('Failed to write ../offer/work/uploads/'.$php_id.'.html');`

Comment: @ekerner That would make the code better, but I wasn't trying to write better code for OP here; I was trying to demonstrate the solution to OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

`file_put_contents` handles the operations open, write and close all in one go – there is not need to call `fwrite` and `fclose` after it. (Not only no need – it doesn’t even make any sense, because with `file_put_contents` you do not even have a file handle to begin with.)

`file_put_contents` returns the number of bytes written, an integer value – and that’s why you get those warnings.